# Converting a dictionary to numpy matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I am a python beginner. I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{'Clinton': [{'ideology': -0.5, 'vote':80}, {'ideology': -0.75, 'vote':90},
 {'ideology': -0.89, 'vote': 99}, 
{'ideology': -0.5, 'vote':80, 'review': "She is a presidential candidate"}],
 'Alexander': [{'ideology': -0.1, 'vote':50}, {'ideology': -0.95, 'vote':20}, 
{'ideology': -0.19, 'vote': 19}, {'ideology': -0.2, 'vote':30, 'review': "Good"}] 
... }
```

I want to convert this dictionary to a numpy matrix like that creating the name as one column, like:

```
   Name  ideology vote review
  Clinton  -0.5    80
  Clinton  -0.75   90
  Clinton  -0.89   99
  Clinton  -0.5    80   "She is a presidential candidate"
 Alexander -0.1    50
 Alexander -0.95   20
 Alexander -0.19   19
 Alexander -0.2    30   "Good"
```

How can I convert this dictionary as a numpy matrix?

One of the problem I have is that the data has more than million observations. So looping over it will take time forever. I want to use the dictionary as a feature vector for a ridge regression.

Comment: For what it's worth: Pandas can easily create a DataFrame from a dict.

Comment: But other than Pandas: have you tried something by creating an empty structured array and using loops over the dict and inner lists to fill the array?

Comment: @Evert I tried it, but the problem is that the data has more than million observations. So looping over it will take time forever. I want to use the dictionary as a feature vector for a ridge regression!

Comment: You should consider pandas in that case.

Comment: Another thing. This may be a case of XY problem since I am guessing that your data did not start as a dictionary. Where did it come from? A database, a CSV file or somewhere else?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is from json.gz file. I used defaultdict and appended features coming from the json.gz.

Comment: Part of your problem might be in the somewhat unconvential/inconvenient form of the data: it's not stored as a nice table, since it avoids repeating the 'Name' column (plus missing entries for 'review'). Hence there is a good chance you'll need to (doubly) loop over your contents whatsoever. But a few million data points: you test it with a few, once it runs properly, you run it once with all your data while possibly writing it to a (CSV) table on the fly (to safe memory) and you're done. Or are you planning to do this hundreds of times with millions of data points?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start.  I'm not worrying about speed at this point (Ipython with python3.4)

```
In [473]: dd = {'Clinton': [{'ideology': -0.5, 'vote':80}, {'ideology': -0.75, 'vote':90},
 {'ideology': -0.89, 'vote': 99}, 
{'ideology': -0.5, 'vote':80, 'review': "She is a presidential candidate"}],
 'Alexander': [{'ideology': -0.1, 'vote':50}, {'ideology': -0.95, 'vote':20}, 
{'ideology': -0.19, 'vote': 19}, {'ideology': -0.2, 'vote':30, 'review': "Good"}]}
...
In [475]: dd
Out[475]: 
{'Alexander': [{'ideology': -0.1, 'vote': 50},
  {'ideology': -0.95, 'vote': 20},
  {'ideology': -0.19, 'vote': 19},
  {'ideology': -0.2, 'vote': 30, 'review': 'Good'}],
 'Clinton': [{'ideology': -0.5, 'vote': 80},
  {'ideology': -0.75, 'vote': 90},
  {'ideology': -0.89, 'vote': 99},
  {'ideology': -0.5, 'vote': 80, 'review': 'She is a presidential candidate'}]}
In [476]: dd.keys()
Out[476]: dict_keys(['Alexander', 'Clinton'])
In [478]: dd.values()
Out[478]: dict_values([[{'ideology': -0.1, 'vote': 50}, {'ideology': -0.95, 'vote': 20}, {'ideology':....}]])
...
```

To make a record array I need a list of tuples, each with a value for each field.  First records with key value pairs.  But value is a list.

(These value lists are evidently a result of using default dictionary with a list append.  It's a nice way of building a dictionary, but unfortunately, for an array we have to unpack it.)

```
In [480]: [(k,v) for k,v in dd.items()]
Out[480]: 
[('Alexander',
  [{'ideology': -0.1, 'vote': 50},
   {'ideology': -0.95, 'vote': 20},
   ....
    'review': 'She is a presidential candidate'}])]
```

Better - lists of lists of tuples with 3 fields:

```
In [483]: [[(k,vv['ideology'],vv['vote']) for vv in v] for k,v in dd.items()]
Out[483]: 
[[('Alexander', -0.1, 50),
  ('Alexander', -0.95, 20),
  ('Alexander', -0.19, 19),
  ('Alexander', -0.2, 30)],
 [('Clinton', -0.5, 80),
  ('Clinton', -0.75, 90),
  ('Clinton', -0.89, 99),
  ('Clinton', -0.5, 80)]]
```

Add the possibly missing `review` field

```
In [484]: [[(k,vv['ideology'],vv['vote'],vv.get('review','')) for vv in v] for k,v in dd.items()]
Out[484]: 
[[('Alexander', -0.1, 50, ''),
  ('Alexander', -0.95, 20, ''),
  ('Alexander', -0.19, 19, ''),
  ('Alexander', -0.2, 30, 'Good')],
 [('Clinton', -0.5, 80, ''),
  ('Clinton', -0.75, 90, ''),
  ('Clinton', -0.89, 99, ''),
  ('Clinton', -0.5, 80, 'She is a presidential candidate')]]
In [485]: ll=[[(k,vv['ideology'],vv['vote'],vv.get('review','')) for vv in v] for k,v in dd.items()]
```

To flatten the list within list, use intertools chain

```
In [486]: from itertools import chain
...
In [488]: list(chain(*ll))
Out[488]: 
[('Alexander', -0.1, 50, ''),
 ('Alexander', -0.95, 20, ''),
 ('Alexander', -0.19, 19, ''),
 ('Alexander', -0.2, 30, 'Good'),
 ('Clinton', -0.5, 80, ''),
 ('Clinton', -0.75, 90, ''),
 ('Clinton', -0.89, 99, ''),
 ('Clinton', -0.5, 80, 'She is a presidential candidate')]
In [489]: ll1=list(chain(*ll))
...
```

Define a dtype:

```
In [491]: dt=np.dtype([('name','U10'),('ideology',float),('vote',int),('review','U100')])

In [492]: data=np.array(ll1,dt)
In [493]: data
Out[493]: 
array([('Alexander', -0.1, 50, ''), ('Alexander', -0.95, 20, ''),
       ('Alexander', -0.19, 19, ''), ('Alexander', -0.2, 30, 'Good'),
       ('Clinton', -0.5, 80, ''), ('Clinton', -0.75, 90, ''),
       ('Clinton', -0.89, 99, ''),
       ('Clinton', -0.5, 80, 'She is a presidential candidate')], 
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('ideology', '<f8'), ('vote', '<i4'), ('review', '<U100')])
```

Looks good.  No iteration during the last array creation step.  There is an iteration when transforming the dictionary to list of tuples.  But that sort of iteration is inevitable when working with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is coming from a `json` file you can load it into Pandas using the [`read_json()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function. This will create a dataframe with the columns that you want. To run a ridge regression, you can use the [`Ridge`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) class from scikit learn (more info [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ridge-regression)). As a Python beginner, it is worth learning pandas and scikit. They are popular packages for data analysis and mining and will provide you with most of the tools you will need. Combining the examples on the two sites:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
import pandas
df = pandas.read_json('json.gz')
y = df['vote']
X = df['ideology']
clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

This is just a rough example. I probably flipped your x- and y-axes and got all the configuration wrong. You would probably need to supply a format string via `orient` parameter of `pandas.read_json()`. That being said, this should give you an idea for how you can get started once you have read the relevant documentation.